# understanding and excel formula I have been using

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

I have been using the following formula to compare strings and show all the matches. It works perfectly but I am trying to increase my overall understanding.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B8,N$1:N$1048576,1,0)),"",1)
```

From what I know this will look up all strings between N1 - N104 and compare them to the string located in B* and return a 1 if found and a 0 if not found what is confusing me is the -- 8576 number what does it do ?

Comment: 1048576 is the last row number-your formula is basically looking at the whole column so you may as well use N:N instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1048576 (2 to the 20th power) is the maximum number of rows in a worksheet in Excel 2007 and later. (In previous versions, it was 65536, or 2 to the 16th power.)

Basically, the `N$1:N$1048576` refers to "all the cells in column N".

**However,** for safety reasons, you should change that part of the formula to the simpler `N:N` - in fact, if I copy your formula, click on an Excel cell, and press Ctrl+V, Excel does that replacement automatically.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [an article on Office.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx), the maximum size of an Excel spreadsheet is:

> 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns

That's where your "8576" is coming from. Your formula is not checking from cell `N1:N104` but rather the entire column of `N`.

Another way of writing your formula would be:

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B8,N:N,1,0)),"",1)`